# while read line strange output

Tags: while-loop, output, sh

I have a script which reads a file line by line.
Each line has many columns separated by white spaces, like:
    1a 1b 1c 1d
    2a 2b 2c 2d
    3a 3b 3c 3d

I want to act on the first column of each line.
So I have the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
file_name=myfile.txt

while read line
do
ve=`cut -d " " -f1`
echo "This is $ve"
done < $file_name
```

but the output is:

```
This is 1a
2a
3a
```

instead of

```
This is 1a
This is 2a
This is 3a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first instance of `cut` eats up all the input.

You probably meant

```
ve=`echo "$line" | cut -d " " -f1`
```

I suggest that you quote your variables well too:

```
#!/bin/sh
file_name=myfile.txt
while read line; do
    ve=`echo "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f1`
    echo "This is $ve"
done < "$file_name"
```